# How to make file visible on SharePoint site (browser)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have deployed script file in document library using module.But this file is not visible on browser.I can see this file in SharePoint Designer.Folders are visible.

Following is the screen shot of designer.

[image]

Following is the screen shot of library view.

[image]

Above error is appearing after I try to drag and drop the same file.

Comment: You need to add some more info, how are you referencing the file, what do you see in Designer. Add code blocks, screenshot, as much info as possible

Comment: Use internet Explorer because Microsoft provide a extra functionality.